# Function keys' roles swapped

Tags: windows-7, toshiba-laptop

I have a Toshiba Satellite C55-A5195 running Windows 7. Earlier, I did not have to hold down the Fn button in order to use any of the function keys. But all of a sudden I have to do so. Explanation for this sudden behaviour or ideas to revert back would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

1. Access the BIOS of your computer by restarting and pressing F10, or whatever key that is shown to **Enter BIOS** . You should be in a
   white and blue menu. You can use the left and right arrow keys to
   cycle through pages and the up and down ones to cycle through
   options. Cycle through the pages until you find one that has a
   setting to do with **Action keys**. Hit Enter to select this and then
   disable it.
2. Hit F10 to exit after saving your changes.

   If you've done everything right, the way your "Fn" key works should
   now be flipped. Hope this helped.

Source : [Seven Forums](http://www.sevenforums.com/customization/152907-can-i-change-fn-key-settings.html)

Comment: Please explain your attempt and where you were stuck.

Comment: i restarted my computer and held down f2 to enter to BIOS mode. this took me to a white and blue menu i then went to the system configuration page and scrolled down to action keys. then choose the disabled option. Then i pressed the F10 key to save and exit. this did not work. i repeated it multiple times and have tried both disable and enable just to see if it would work.